# How to paste multiline SQL statements into the sqlite3 shell

Tags: shell, sqlite

I use a script to generate CREATE statements for tables and want to paste these statements into the SQLite command shell. Unfortunately it does not work as expected, because the line break seems to cause trouble.

When I copy the following example table

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable (
    columnA INTEGER, 
    columnB VARCHAR(2), 
    columnC INTEGER
);
```

into the SQLite command shell, I get this result:

```
sqlite>     CREATE TABLE ExampleTable (
   ...>
```

and the shell waits for input until I press the semicolon (;). Is this linked to the separator? I tried setting it to ';' manually but there was no effect. I would expect the shell to accept the commands regardless of the format of its input string. The very same command works for instance in the Firefox Addon SQLite Manager, also I could read them from a file. For the quick test nevertheless, I would rather just paste the CREATE statements. I am sure that is a very easy thing to do, I just could not find the proper hint. Thanks!

Comment: You have pasted only the first line. This appears to be a problem with your text editor or shell.

Comment: multi-valued insert supported by SQLite since version 3.7.11.
Maybe yours is older version.

Comment: @CL: I copied the complete table definition and the sqlite shell stops after the first line waiting for input. I can copy the same statements into the MySQL shell without this phenomenon. My sqlite version is : SQLite version 3.9.2 2015-11-02 18:31:45

Comment: What shell are you using? The Windows console?

Comment: @CL: I use GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
in Linux Mint. Does the pasting work with your setup?

Comment: Which terminal? How exactly are doing the copy/paste?

Comment: I have the same problem with sqlite shell v.3.14.1 started from zsh 5.0.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) on ubuntu linux 14.04

Answer (score 1):

1. Save CREATE statements to txt file
2. Open database in SQLite command shell
3. Use command .read file_name.txt

Answer (score 0):

This issue is discussed [in this forum](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Command-line-not-accepting-multi-line-statements-td92309.html).

What I've found:

- sqlite shell v.3.14.1 - has this issue;
- sqlite shell v.3.8.2 - don't have this issue;
- sqlite shell v.3.16.2 (the latest binary that you can download at the moment) - don't have this issue;

So you can just download the new version.